# SQL Server appears to correctly interpret non-supported string literal formats

Tags: sql-server

Have an instance of SQL Server 2012 that appears to correctly interpret string literal dates whose formats are not listed in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#supported-string-literal-formats-for-date) (though note these docs are for SQL Server 2017).

Eg. I have a TSV with a column of dates of the format `%d-%b-%y` (see https://devhints.io/datetime#date-1) which looks like "25-FEB-93". However, this throws type errors when trying to copy the data into the SQL Server table (via `mssql-tools` `bcp` binary). Yet, when testing on another table in SQL Server, I can do something like...

```sql
select top 10 * from account where BIRTHDATE > '25-FEB-93'
```

without any errors. All this, even though the given format is not listed in the docs for acceptable date formats and it apparently also can't be used as a castable string literal when writing in new records. Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the given format is not listed in the docs for acceptable date formats

That means it's not supported, and does not have documented behavior.  There's lots of strings that under certain regional settings will convert due to quirks in the parsing implementation.

It's a performance-critical code path, and so the string formats are not rigorously validated on conversion.  You're expected to ensure that the strings are in a supported format.

So you may need to load the column as a varchar(n) and then convert it.  eg

```
declare @v varchar(200) = '25-FEB-93'
select convert(datetime,replace(@v,'-',' '),6)
```

Per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) format 6 is `dd mon YY`, but note that this conversion "works" without replacing the `-` with , but that's an example of the behavior you observed.