# BCP throwing "Invalid character value for cast" for valid date format?

Tags: sql-server, bcp

Using `bcp` from the `mssql-tools` package (on CentOS 7). Attempting to copy a TSV file into a SQL Server 2012 table and getting the error:

> @ Row 1, Column 4: Invalid character value for cast specification @#

Opening the tsv in `vi` and using `:set list` to reveal tab delimiters, this record looks like...

```sh
123456^IJOHN DOE^IJOHN DOE^I26 SEP 96^IM^I1234-2134^IY^IUNIT F^I918 ASDF^IZXCVB^I12^I1342^I12345^I^I1^I^I1234^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I123^I^I^I1234^I^IJOHN DOE^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^IY^I^I^I^I^I0^I0^I^I0^I^I^I^I^I1234^I^I^I^I SOLUTIONS^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I123^I^I1^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^Iasdf1234^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I1234^I^I^I^I^I2019-10-07$
```

So we can see the 4th column is a date string literal of the form `dd mon yy`. To me this should match the alphabetical format in the SQL Server [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#supported-string-literal-formats-for-date)

> dd mon[,][yy]yy

(though note this is for SQL Server 2017 as I could not find the docs for 2012) and have confirmed that the 4th column in the destination table is in fact expecting a `date` type. From querying the info schema via

```sql
SELECT ORDINAL_POSITION, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
       , IS_NULLABLE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MYTABLE'
```

```sql
ORDINAL_POSITION    COLUMN_NAME      DATA_TYPE  CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH    IS_NULLABLE
1                   ACCOUNT_ID       bigint     NULL    NO
2                   ACCOUNT_NAME     varchar    160     YES
3                   CONTACT_PERSON   varchar    410     YES
4                   BIRTHDATE        date       NULL    YES
5                   SEX              varchar    50      YES
...
```

The BCP command looks like:

```sh
RECOMMEDED_IMPORT_MODE="-c"
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/bcp "$TABLENAME" in $filename \
                -S $DEST_IP \
                -U $USER -P $PASSWORD \
                -d $DEST_DB \
                $RECOMMEDED_IMPORT_MODE \
                -t "\t" \
                -e $EXPORT_STAGE/$TABLENAME/$TABLENAME.bcperror.log
```

Anyone know what could be going on here? Any further debugging suggestions?

Comment: Why do you need to post another version of your prior [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58278085/sql-server-appears-to-correctly-interpret-non-supported-string-literal-formats)?

Comment: @SMor In this question I have modified the record value to actually match a valid date format as specified in the docs (`dd mon yy` rather than `dd-mon-yy` in the other question). Yet even after using what I would think is now a valid date format, still getting type errors from bcp, so asked a bcp-focused question. The previous question asks why sql-server seemed to be able to handle an invalid date format (from the perspective of bcp and the sql-server docs) when querying, this question is more asking what bcp's problem could be with a supposedly valid date format string.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a tab hidden in one of my data fields that was pushing the date in to the wrong column, hence the invalid cast error.

Switch on error logging by using `-e C:\path\to\logfile` and check out the number of columns in your errored row.